# Linqpad failing on tasks when loading three scripts

Tags: c#, linqpad

In Linqpad 7, I am developing a complete testing environment for our REST apis. I currently have three scripts, that constitutes the testing environment:

1. **core_rest_extensions.linq** - This defines various extension methods for generating a fluent api for wiring up a REST client (HttpClient). This is a statement script.
2. **core_rest_auth.linq** - Authentication for our REST services and a common RestClient class, that inherits from HtpClient. Configuration etc. Loads #1. This is a program script.
3. **extensions.linq** - Extension methods for the RestClient for a specific set of REST calls. Loads #1. and #2. This is a program script.

Both #2 and #3 have a simple `Main()` method that I use to test the basic connection. This works fine in both scripts.

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var apiKey = ""; // Any key token with access. 
    var ocpKey = ""; // OCP-Apim-Subscription-key.
    var baseUrl = ""; // The base url of the client.
    var client = await RestClient.CreateClient(apiKey, ocpKey, baseUrl);
}
```

A fourth script then contains all the concrete the test cases for a specific API. This loads the 3 other scripts, in the mentioned order. It is a program script.

The exact same Main() in this script fails with an exception:
`InvalidOperationException: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).`
This occurs in an extension method called `PostAsync`, which is defined in the first script.

The RestClient class is defined like this, in the **core_rest_auth** script:

```cs
public partial class RestClient : HttpClient
{
    public static async Task<RestClient> CreateClient(string apiKey, string ocpKey, string baseUrl)
    {
        var client = (RestClient)new RestClient() {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl),
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", ocpKey);
        var auth = await client.AuthenticationLogin(new LoginDTO { ApiToken = apiKey });
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", auth.Token);

        return client;
    }

    public async Task<TokenDTO> AuthenticationLogin(LoginDTO dto)
        => await this.PostAsync<TokenDTO>("authentication/login", (r) => r.AsJson(dto));
}

public class LoginDTO
{
    public string? ApiToken { get; set; }
}

public class TokenDTO
{
    public string? Token { get; set; }
}
```

The pertinent methods in the **core_rest_extensions** scripts are here:

```cs
public static async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string path, Action<HttpRequestMessage>? requestPre = null) where T : class
{
    using (var req = path.Uri().Post())
    {
         requestPre?.Invoke(req);
        using (var res = client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            return await res.ValidateSuccess().ReadAsAsync<T>();
        }
   }
}

public static Uri Uri(this string text) => new Uri(text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

public static HttpRequestMessage Post(this Uri uri) => new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ValidateSuccess(this Task<HttpResponseMessage> msg)
{
    var m = await msg;
    if (m.IsSuccessStatusCode) return m;

    string result = null;
    try
    {
        result = await m.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch { }
    throw new HttpResponseInfoException(m, result);
}

public static async Task<T?> ReadAsAsync<T>(this Task<HttpResponseMessage> msg) where T : class
{
    var m = await msg;
    if (m.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.EndsWith("/json", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        try
        {
            return await m.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string content = await m.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw new DeserializeErrorException(content, ex);
        }
    }
}

public static HttpRequestMessage AsJson(this HttpRequestMessage msg, object content)
{
    if (content == null)
        return msg;

    var opts = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web) { IgnoreNullValues = true };
    var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(content, content.GetType(), opts);

    msg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(json);
    msg.Content.Headers.ContentLength = json.Length;
    msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return msg;
}
```

As I mentioned, the *exact* same `Main()` definition in script #2 and #3 works fine. In script #4, it fails with the exception above.
The exception occurs in the `ValidateSuccess` extension method.

I am not sure how to interpret this, but it feels like Linqpad is unable to keep tasks running correctly when more than two scripts are loaded into another.

1 #load - Fine.
2 #loads - Fine.
3 #loads - Task is disposed before it runs to completion.

Anyone have any insights into why this may be?

Comment: There's far too much code in here to make it easy for us to help with. There are also various errors and references to things we can't see either. Try paring this down into a [mre].

Comment: Besides what DavidG just commented, I have LinqPad app comprised of 12 individual separate files, with several namespaces, working perfectly. What you lose organizing like this is that you cannot debug stepping into  between **.linq** files.

Comment: So, as a suggestion, cooy all your code inside one file and debug there. As a bonus you will maybe able to use it in dotnetfiddle too . Anyway, you should do Unit tests in individual files instead of integration tests like you are doing now.

Comment: @DavidG I know there's a lot of code, but that is actually boiled down from the actual script files. I can't reduce it any further, except the HttpClient call. I realise now that the extension methods there are not defined in my example.

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz Oh, we do unit tests. This is for testing the deployed APIs.

Comment: With all of the extension methods you have here, it's really hard to follow the logic. I particularly don't like the `ValidateSuccess` method and the way you don't await that before passing the resulting task into the `ReadAsAsync` method. I would suggest simplifying that and then see if the error still happens.

Comment: Thomas, of course you do unit test; who in the world don't? ;) What I meant is, because in LinqPad you cannot debug stepping into other .linq modules, a simple unit test that uses, for example, an extension method, if an error occurs there it will fail with not so useful error msg in the original module, instead of step into the extension method and fail properly there. And that's why I reclassified this unit tests in integration tests...

Comment: Oh, I agree on the extensions methods. Problem is that this is something that has been built up over years. There is a massive library of tests etc. that uses this. So, I cannot just start refactoring this. 

My question, though, whether there is an issue in Linqpad when #loading more than a couple of scripts, has more or less been answered, as @MarceloScofanoDiniz indicates he has scripts that loads as much as 12 scripts. 

I am still baffled, **why** this is an issue here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.
I started reducing extension methods, until I got *another* error.
Specifically "Method not found" exception for the `HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync` method from `System.Net.Http.Json`.

I then started comparing namespaces and references between the scripts, and lo and behold. The script that failed has some extra references the others didn't.

I am guessing one of these referenced an older version of `System.Net.Http.Json` which does not have this specific method.

Once I removed the extra references, I had no errors.

Comment: Glad to see that you solved it. And this is my practice: for all code that is not short and trivial, if it originally is divided in a lot of files and namespaces I first condense all in one big .linq file, and see it run once, with no failure, at least. If it is OK, and I really need to mirror some project, I move it to separate files. but I never begin to debug old code in separate files...
I already had my share of too many cryptic failures...